# UITextFieldDelegate not working if instantiated in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift

If I instantiate the delegate in the ViewController, all works fine, the delegate gets called correctly:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var topText: UITextField
    let topDelegate = UpperTextDelegate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        topText.delegate = topDelegate
    }
    // GOOD, DELEGATE METHODS ARE GETTING CALLED AS EXPECTED
```

If I instantiate the delegate INSIDE the `viewDidLoad` method, things break, the delegate methods do not get called.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var topText: UITextField

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        topText.delegate = UpperTextDelegate()
    }
    // BAD, DELEGATE METHODS ARE NOT GETTING CALLED :-(
```

Please what is going on here?

### ----------

This is the delegate:

```
import UIKit

class UpperTextDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.text = ""
    }   
}
```

Comment: Put code of UpperTextDelegate()

Comment: Are you sure delegate methods called after you set the delegate? If it called before `viewDidLoad` of ViewController, the delegate method of `UpperTextDelegate` will not be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your code build correctly because I thought a weak property had to be optional (after all it might be set to nil).

In any case the weak declaration is what is causing the problem.

When you declare a property weak the class does not retain a reference to it and so it will only be valid as long as the scope of the object itself is valid.  In your first example the 'topDelegate' is defined in the class itself and so is in scope as long as the class exists.  In the second example the 'topDelegate' is defined within the viewDidLoad method and it's only in scope for as long as that method exists which is why no delegate methods are called after the viewDidLoad is finished.

Something must retain the 'topDelegate' so either you have to define it in the class (in which case why not just remove the weak reference) or something else should retain it.

Answer (score 3):

The second code doesn't work because you don't hold strong reference to your delegate. You just instantiate an UpperTextDelegate object and assign it to a weak property. It gets released instantly.

UITextField's delegate property is weak because otherwise you would always get a **retain cycle**. (Your ViewController holds reference to its view -> it holds reference to its subview (UITextField) -> that would hold reference to its delegate that is you ViewController.)

Your code will work if you define the variable in your class (must be optional or you have to assign value to it in init()) and then you assign a value to it in your viewDidLoad.

I suggest to google up **ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)** and **delegation pattern** in iOS.